# EhCache - remove expired element (because of timeToIdleSeconds or timeToLiveSeconds) without try to get it?

Tags: ehcache

The EhCache documentation says:

- Accessing an entry in myCache that has been idle for more than an hour (timeToIdleSeconds) causes that element to be evicted.
- If an entry expires but is not accessed, and no resource constraints force eviction, then the expired entry remains in place.
- getting an expired element will remove it from the cache and return null.

If you implement and register a CacheEventListener to receive that an element is expired, you can see the event is fired when you try to get an expired element, but not after the 'timeToIdleSeconds'.

Is it possible to force removing the expired element after it is expired?
Because in my case after this time no one will try to get it again.

Thank you.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838039/ehcache-does-not-remove-element-from-memory-on-eviction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done it with the following code:

```
cache.evictExpiredElements();
cache.flush();
```

Comment: I did it in a similar way. I searched a solution with AUTO-evict, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to do it automatically too, but there is a tip in EhCache docs - `expired` != `removed`, so I had to do it manually

Answer (score 2):

In Version 3 of EhCache and up you cant use `cache.evictExpiredElements()` anymore and most likely you shouldn't :)

But if you have to, here is my solution:

```
final Iterator<Entry<String, Bean>> iterator = cache.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next();
}
```

This will force the cache to get every element in it, return null for expired elements and remove them. In addition I created an `CacheEventListener` to catch the eviction event to do some stuff.

As mentioned before, analyze your usecase carefully and make sure that there is no better way than brute force.